# python merge panda dataframes keep dates

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I'd like to merge two dataframes together but add in a column based on some logic.  A simplified example of my dataframes are below:

```
 DF_1:
 domain               ttl           nameserver               file_date
 fakedomain.com       86400         ns1.fakedomain.com       8/8/2008
 fakedomainz.com      86400         ns1.fakedomainz.com      8/8/2008


 DF_2:
 domain               ttl           nameserver               file_date
 fakedomain.com       86400         ns1.fakedomain.com       9/8/2008
 fakedomainz.com      86400         ns1.fakedomainz.com      9/8/2008
```

What I want to do is merge both of these dataframes into a single data frame that looks like this:

```
 DF_2:
 domain               ttl           nameserver               first seen     last seen
 fakedomain.com       86400         ns1.fakedomain.com       8/8/2008       9/8/2008
 fakedomainz.com      86400         ns1.fakedomainz.com      8/8/2008       9/8/2008
```

I can't find a way to merge them and keep the dates.  I also want to make sure the dates are in the correct fields.  Its important to note that I'm creating the dates from regex pulled from the file names.  I will also be running this script continuously over time so the first seen date will only change when something else changes e.g. the domain changes its name server.

The only way I can think of is to merge them with renamed date columns, then loop over the entire dataframe sorting the dates appropriately but this seems inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure which process produces these frames or whether it is a continuous stream of new data, but to just comment on the substance of the question, you could do like so:

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

s1="""
domain               ttl           nameserver               file_date
fakedomain.com       86400         ns1.fakedomain.com       8/8/2008
fakedomainz.com      86400         ns1.fakedomainz.com      8/8/2008
"""

s2="""
domain               ttl           nameserver               file_date
fakedomain.com       86400         ns1.fakedomain.com       9/8/2008
fakedomainz.com      86400         ns1.fakedomainz.com      9/8/2008
"""
```

Then,

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(StringIO(s1), sep='\s+',parse_dates=['file_date']  )
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(StringIO(s2), sep='\s+',parse_dates=['file_date']  )
```

And assuming that you want the unique combination of `domain`, `ttl`, and `nameserver`, along with first and last observation for that combination, concatenate the frames and grab min and max dates.

```
result = pd.concat([df1,df2]).reset_index().groupby(['domain','ttl','nameserver']).file_date.agg({'first_seen':'min','last_seen':'max'})
```

And finally:

```
result
                                          first_seen last_seen
domain          ttl   nameserver                              
fakedomain.com  86400 ns1.fakedomain.com    8/8/2008  9/8/2008
fakedomainz.com 86400 ns1.fakedomainz.com   8/8/2008  9/8/2008
```

Comment: This works perfectly for me.  I had to make a small change and make the date a datetime object and then everything fell in place.  My only question is what happens if fakedomain.com switches from  ns1.fakedomain.com to ns2.fakedomain.com back to ns1.fakedomain.com.  Will ns1.fakedomain.com show the first and last dates?  I'd like to capture the transaction of it moving between the 2 without overwriting the previous dates.

Comment: This example will treat a combination of `fakedomain.com` and `ns1.fakedomain.com` as unique, and thus different from, say, `fakedomain.com` and `ns2.fakedomain.com`. Accordingly, if you have many observations within each of these groups, the values picked will per this be the smallest and largest of the `file_date` series.